M Code of UTF-32 Encoded Emoji in Power Query is not processed by SAP HANA
I wrote this M code in Power Query to create a column whose cells contain this emoji :
#"Added Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "Column Name", each Character.FromNumber(128674))

I want to represent a ship in my column, so every cell will contain the Ship Emoji.
But I got this error:
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation; 257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "": line 36 col 5 (at pos 2176)
Details:
 DataSourceKind = SapHana
 DataSourcePath = xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx
 OdbcErrors=[Table]]

I guess that I am not able to represent a 32-UTF emoji in Power Query.
How can I solve this issue? I do not want to use DAX to represent the emoji, I want to do in Power Query.
Thanks
let
    Source = SapHana.Database(DataSource, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    Contents = Source{[Name="XX"]}[Data],
    Schema = Contents{[Name="Schema"]}[Data],
    Table = Schema{[Name="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(Table,
        {
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "Table", {"columns"}, {"Columns Names"}}
        }),
    #"Added Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Items", "Columns Name", each ""),
    #"Added Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Column", "Column Name1", each "⭐"),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Column1", "Conditional Column Name", each if [XX] = "xx" then [XX] else null),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Conditional Column",{{"XX", type datetime}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each not Text.StartsWith([XXYY], "xxyy "))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"


This is nothing to do with PQ. It works fine in my Excel demo. The issue is something else and looks related to the SAP connector although why this is going back to SAP, I have no idea. Try making this your last step in your query as it is not a PQ problem.

I made it as the last step, but I am getting the same error. This step has nothing to do with SAP HANA, or getting data from SAP HANA, because I am implementing it after getting the data, but I am still having the same issue.

Paste your entire query. This is definitely not a PQ issue. The SAP connector could be implementing some kind of faulty query folding which is why it is going back to SAP.

here is the complete code

I added the complete code to a new answer, because it is to long to write in a comment.
Can you please see it there?

Maybe it is going back to sap with query folding?

Looks like broken query folding to me. Move your filter above the special char lines (make sure these are last). Also, add a step in between that definitely breaks query folding.
